# Error running exe generated from Framework7 CLI Electron

Tags: cordova, electron, html-framework-7

I am running into an issue trying to run the boiler-plate application that is created from the Framework7 CLI as an electron app. I am able to run “framework7 cordova build electron” with no problems from my Windows 10 machine. However, when I try to run the EXE I get the following error in a browser developer console: “Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND logo.png”

Is there a fix for this?
Thanks!

Comment: I think you try to use logo, but your logo its not in a dist folder, so that just copy your logo to same path for exe and your issue will be fix....

Comment: Hello @AneesHikmatAbuHmiad. I tried what you suggested but the issue still happens.  Could you please clarify what you mean about "dist folder?" Could you indicate its location? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @vbguyny, "dist folder" its refer to destination folder (which folder have an exe election file), so that if you try my suggest and its not work, we need to make sure what is the real path for logo? where is set? ```Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND logo.png``` refer to 404, cont locate file...so that you need to make sure if logo for example in img/logo, you need to create a new directory in election result folder with directory name img/logo ...and so on...

Comment: @Anees ikmatAbuHmiad Ok, I created the folder img and copied a logo.png in there but I still get the error.